# Unable to load template file

Tags: templates, zend-framework, smarty

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file '../index/index.tpl'' in 
/var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:174 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(551): Smarty_Internal_Template->isExisting(true) 
#1 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/application/tmp/smarty_compile/898ca70906754084b81f61d3ce7baee3b11bd8d3.file.layout.tpl.php(46): Smarty_Internal_Template->getRenderedTemplate() 
#2 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(436): include('/var/www/docs/s...') 
#3 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(568): Smarty_Internal_Template->renderTemplate() 
#4 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(328): Smarty_Internal_Template->getRenderedTemplate() 
#5 /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(370): Smarty->fetch('/var/www/docs/s...', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) 
#6 /v in /var/www/docs/sw.com/public/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 174
```

I am using smarty template with zend framework and in that I create one more module like admin.In that module Controller is working and layout.tpl file is also working but problem is that when i add include file syntax in layout.tpl file that time same error is coming.

```
IndexController.php

<?php

class Admin_IndexController extends Models_UserCommonController 
{

function init() 
    {

    parent::init();

}

public function indexAction()
 {
    $this->view->assign('T_Body', '../index/index.tpl');
}
}
?>

layout.tpl    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>{$SITE_TITLE}</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Hello</p>

{include file="$T_Body"}

</body>
</html>

index.php
```

## Admin

I done same thing in windows its working but in ubuntu its not working. 
I set all permissions and check everything path and all. 
Default module is working in ubuntu but admin module is not working

Comment: It sounds like your path to the `index.tpl` file is simply wrong. Double check if it is connecting to the right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure about the Smarty implementation but you have to remember that PHPs working directory is your projects root path.

You'd probably want to assign it absolutely with this manner:

```
$this->view->assign('T_Body', __DIR__ . '/../index/index.tpl');
```

Remember though that this only holds true for Zend Framework 2! Your code suggests that you're not using the second version but rather ZF1. Otherwise you absolutely should move forward and use namespaces and follow the tutorial on how to build your Controllers.